# Emacs Elisp Overriding Default Value

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have several abbrev defined that I was accessible everywhere except in latex mode. I defined

```
(setq-default abbrev-mode t)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode -1)))
```

But whenever I open a latex file it still has abbrev mode enabled. What's going on?

Comment: are you certain it recognizes the file as a latex file?

Comment: Which LaTeX mode do you use?  AUCTeX uses `LaTeX-mode-hook` rather than `latex-mode-hook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that AUCTex uses LaTeX-mode-hook. Thanks to stefan in the comment for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with latex before, but for me the following works fine:

> (setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.lat\\'" . latex-mode) auto-mode-alist))
>   (setq-default abbrev-mode t)
>   (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode -1)))

`M-x abbrev-mode`
%Abbrev mode enabled in current buffer

Please make sure the emacs recognized your file as a latex file, the first line I wrote should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Emacs already recognizes the latex files and applies the correct mode. The other two were what I had. It still doesn't work. Maybe it's something with my particular version of emacs

Comment: @PaulMcVay the hook worked fine on my machine when I tried it. Must be a version diff...