# why is LaTex mode replaced by Fundamental mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, emacs24, auctex

Before I installed some packages and add some configurations in `.emacs`, the `.tex` file in Emacs is in `LaTex` mode. After I changes `.emacs`, the `.tex` file is opened in `Fundamental` mode. All the functionalities of `Latex` mode works well, like compile and view. If I enable the `LaTex-Math` mode, the `Fundamental` mode will become `LaTex/MP` mode, and when I disable the `LaTex-Math` mode, it becomes `LaTex/P` mode.

How can I open a `.tex` file with `LaTex` mode, rather than `Fundamental` mode?

Comment: It is difficult for anyone to really know what you did to break AUCTeX functionality because there are a zillion things that may have happened.  In general, the `auto-mode-alist` stores information about what major-modes are associated with certain file extensions.  You can type `M-x describe-variable RET auto-mode-alist RET` and see what it looks like.  Inasmuch as a barebones Emacs associates `.tex` files with the built-in `tex-mode`, you have likely broken the `auto-mode-alist` -- but there are probably other problems too.  Recursively bisect your user-configuration by comment out stuff.

Comment: @lawlist, Thanks, I've never tried this method before, and it was solved by commenting `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(flyspell-mode t))` this sentence out.

Comment: That is an error, which may have caused your Elisp configuration to stop from loading.  In the future, you may wish to check your `*Messages*` buffer and also set `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the top when debugging, and comment it out when you are done.  Instead of `'(flyspell-mode t)`, use `'turn-on-flyspell`.  The function `add-hook` expects the second argument to be a *function*, not a list -- Emacs thinks `'(flyspell-mode t)` is a list in this context, which throws an error.

Comment: it is a duplicate of a very recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324504/emacs-elisp-overriding-default-value/42327657?noredirect=1